# Prevent last logged on user's wallpaper from displaying on logon screen

Tags: desktop-customization, windows-2000

I'm wondering how one can disable the last logged on user's background on the logon screen. Currently, bginfo runs as part of the logon script and writes the computer name and username to the desktop. When a user logs out, the desktop background is still there. I didn't notice this on computers that didn't use bginfo since the default blue wallpaper is used for both.

I helped someone resolve a similar issue on his computer where upon logon, his old wallpaper would be briefly visible and then the new wallpaper would apply: disabling Active Desktop fixed this issue. However, I'm not using Active Desktop.

I have the Group Policy to not display the last logged in user *enabled*, but it doesn't really "work" in the sense that, since the last logged on user's wallpaper is display on the logon screen, one can still tell who was last logged in.

The last user's wallpaper still appears even after a restart, so it's not just some transient thing. How can I disable this behavior - e.g. force the logon screen to always show the plain, vanilla wallpaper and not any user's background?

*Comment: I did notice this behavior on Windows XP machines as well years ago, and I think it must be the same thing in play. That organization did not fix this bug, or didn't care.*

Comment: There is also the possibility that this is a graphic driver issue and not a Windows issue. The graphic driver may reuse the desktop buffer causing the old bg image to appear until the new one has been completely loaded. I even encountered a machine that was showing the last desktop image after a reboot, therefore it could only reside in VRAM. Anyway you tagged the question Win2K - are you serious about still using such an old Windows version for desktop users?

Comment: @Robert That's an interesting possibility. How would I be able to remediate that or test if that is indeed the case? IMNSHO, Windows 2000 was the pinnacle of Windows, so yes. With kernel modifications, we have all the latest software running just great on Win2K. No annoying Windows 10 bloat or anything. Everything works just the way it should. Windows 7 is good, but it's amazing just how straightforward everything is in W2K, no nonsense anywhere.

Comment: *shaking the head* Good luck if you ever come in contact with a modern malware that uses EternalBlue or a similar exploit. Then good bye to the whole domain.

Comment: @Robert Computers don't mysteriously and automatically infect themselves; that comes as the result of dumb users doing stupid things. Oh, by the way, I don't run any antivirus at all, and we've been doing just fine. Yes, all computers are networked and online. As long as users don't navigate to sketchy sites or download sketchy attachments, a lot of those worries are not realizable.

Comment: @Robert Also, the EternalBlue exploit relies on Terminal Services, which doesn't exist in Windows 2000 Professional. In Server you can just disable the service. Also, the WannyCry patch is included in the kernel modifications for Windows 2000. So as it is, my Windows 2000 systems are pretty secure anyways